# How can I align Actionbar's ImageView to center

Tags: android-layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_black"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Image is bias right side, little bit... How can I align Image(which is inside of actionbar) to center.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/full_rate"
                android:baselineAlignBottom="false"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Main attribute for remove padding Add 3 Lines in Toolbar

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```